# plotly color of annotation

Tags: text, colors, annotations

I have a scatter plot which represents a KPI. Below the KPI value I have a green rectangle, above a red rectangle created both with "fig.add_hrect()". I add text to indicate "KPI not satisfied" using:

```
        fig.add_hrect(y0=sbf._KPI_CODERES_THRESHOLD, y1=residual_max,
                      annotation_text='KPI not satisfied', annotation_position='top',
                      fillcolor='red', opacity=0.05, line_width=0)
```

The text is in black and I cannot find a way to have the annotation text colored red.

Any help appreciated,
Tx/ALain

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fig.update_annotations()` to change the annotation text. Below is a sample of the same...

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width") ## My dummy plot
fig.add_hrect(y0=1, y1=1, annotation_text='KPI not satisfied', annotation_position='top', 
              fillcolor='red', opacity=0.05, line_width=0)

fig.update_annotations(font=dict(family="sans serif", size=18, color="red"))
```

[image]

Comment: this font=dict(color='white') is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add `annotation_font_color='red'` inside `fig.add_hrect()`.
So will be:

```
fig.add_hrect(
    y0=1,
    y1=1, 
    annotation_text='KPI not satisfied',
    annotation_font_color='red',
    ...
)
```